# How to get a 5-Dimensional output after torch.nn.Conv2d layer in PyTorch?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am working on a project based on the OpenPose research paper that I read two weeks ago. In that, the model is supposed to give a 5-dimensional output. For example, `torch.nn.conv2d()` gives a 4-D output of the following shape: `(Batch_size, n_channels, input_width, input_height)`. What I need is an output of the following shape: `(Batch_size, n_channels, input_width, input_height, 2)`. Here `2` is a fixed number not subject to any changes.
The `2` is there because each entry is a 2-dimensional vector hence for each channel in every pixel position, there are 2 values hence, the added dimension.

What will be the best way to do this? 
I thought about having 2 seperate branches for each of the vector values but the network is very deep and I would like to be as Computationally efficient as possible.

Comment: Maybe `conv3d` is useful for you?

Comment: What is the input shape?

Comment: The input is an image that is passed on to the first 10 layers of pre-trained VGG-19 layers. The output are the detected feature maps(4D). These are supposed to be transformed into a 5D output

Answer (score 0):

So you are effectively looking to compute feature maps which are *interpreted* as 2-dimensional vectors. Unless there is something fancy math-wise happening there, you are probably fine with just having twice as many output channels: `(batch_size, n_channels * 2, width, height)`, and then reshaping it as

```
output5d = output4d.reshape(
      output4d.shape[0],
      output4d.shape[1] / 2,
      2,
      output4d.shape[2],
      output4d.shape[3]
)
```

which gives you a shape of `(batch_size, n_channels, 2, width, height)`. If you really want to have `2` as the last dimension, you can use [`transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.transpose):

```
output5d = output5d.transpose(2, 4)
```

but if there is no strong argument in favor of this layout, I would suggest you do not transpose as it always costs a bit of performance.

Comment: Great, I will try this out!